# Select Object randomly from group

Tags: python, add-on

I'm currently creating an addon for Blender and got stuck at following task:
-I want to select one object with an unknown name from a group with known name
-I want this object to be an object instance that can be used in the following code

I tried many different things, but none of the worked.
One Idea was to list all objects of the group and than select one.

newest try:

```
bpy.ops.object.select_same_group(group=scene.object_group)

# select one object randomly from the actives
scene.object_group is a strong property with the group name
```

Comment: Can you share your code with us? :)

Comment: code is added above

Answer (score 3):

Get the group via `bpy.data.groups`, all objects of that group are accessible via a Group's `objects` property:

```
import bpy
import random

group_name = "Group"

group = bpy.data.groups.get(group_name)
assert group is not None

first_ob = group.objects[0]

random_ob = random.choice(group.objects)
```

If you wanna select another object from a random group the active object is in, use `.users_group`:

```
import bpy
from random import choice

scene = bpy.context.scene
ob = bpy.context.object

random_group = choice(ob.users_group)
obs = random_group.objects[:]
obs.remove(ob)

try:
    random_ob = choice(obs)
except IndexError:
    # no other object in chosen group
    pass

#bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
for ob in scene.objects:
    ob.select = False
random_ob.select = True
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = random_ob
```

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!
works perfectly
You solved my problem I've worked on over 1 week.
now my last part of my random array Addon is finished.
I'll publish the new version on my homepage soon.

Comment: @frameworker if CoDEmanX has solved your problem you can [accept his answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @CoDEmanX Nice one, but what if group_name is not "group"? I've already been thinking about this yesterday and ended up with this: https://gist.github.com/p2or/526243d1af3fd21cd74d It was hard to find out in which group the object is? Do you know an easier way?

Comment: In your question you said the name of the group was known. Updated my answer to show how to select a random object from a random group the current object is in.

Comment: @CoDEmanX Thanks for updating the answer, ob.users_group also solved my issue :) I've missed that yesterday. Thanks again!